# Does there exist such a number?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

> Does there exist a $2n$-digit number $\overline{a_{2n}a_{2n-1}\ldots a_1}$ (for an arbitrary $n$) for which the following equality holds:
>   $$\overline{a_{2n}\ldots a_1}= (\overline{a_n \ldots a_1})^2?$$

I was thinking of saying the given statement is equivalent to $$10^{2n-1}a_{2n}+10^{2n-2}a_{2n-1}+\cdots+10^{0}a_1 = (10^{n-1}a_n+10^{n-2}a_{n-1}+\cdots+10^{0}a_1)^2.$$ What can I do from here?

Comment: $25=5^2$, $36=6^2$. But also $5776=76^2$,  $390625=625^2$ and many more

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The question says for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: Well, that could be interopreted as "does there exist at least on $n$ that I may choose arbitrarily". But I'm writing up a "yes" answer for all $n$ right now

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This was an IMO Longlisted question, so I think the arbitrary $n$ interpretation is right.

Comment: It's all a tempest in a teapot because ... see below.

Answer (score 3):

It works for all positive $n$.  The proof involves **10-adic idempotents** (https://divisbyzero.com/2008/12/29/a-10-adic-number-that-is-a-zero-divisor/).  These are 10-adic numbers that are their own squares so they are automatically their own cubes, their own fourth powers, etc.

In ordinary numbers only $0$ and $1$ satisfy this condition.  But in 10-adics there are two additional idempotents:

$I_6\equiv...109376$

$I_5\equiv...890625$

These "extra" idempotents have the property that if you truncate one of them by taking only finitely many digits from the right, then the square reproduces those digits.  For example, truncate $I_6$ at three digits and square:

$376^2=141,376\equiv376$ mod $10^3$

Here we were lucky to get a $2n$ digit square number; had we tried to do this with six terminal digits we would have found $109,376^2=$ an 11-digit number instead of the 12 digits we wanted.  But then $I_5$ saves the day because $890,625^2$ has the full 12 digits.  Can we show that $I_5$ always steps up when $I_6$ fails or vice versa?

If we add up the idempotents $I_5$ and $I_6$ an amazing thing happens (OK, I was amazed when I first saw it).  They just add up to $1$!  That means, since they are not individually $0$ and $1$, the units digits must add up to $11$ ($5+6$, of course), and at every other place value the digits add up to $9$.  The $9$ sums become $10$ with the carry digit $1$ added in, giving $0$ in the sum and reproducing the carry digit $1$.  So ... When we take both of these idempotents and truncate them at the the same number $n$ digits from the right, at least one of the leading digits must be $5$ or more.  And that would be a large enough leading digit so that the square has the full complement of $2n$ digits without using a leading zero.

So here is a foolproof solution for any positive $n$:

1)  Work out $I_5$ and $I_6$ to $n$ digits from the right.

2)  Pick the $n$-digit truncatoon with the larger leading digit.

3)  Square the number picked in (2).

In some cases the truncated idempotent with the smaller leading digit works too, e.g. $n=3$ gives both $376^2=141,376$ and $625^2=390,625$.  Such values of $n$ give two solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of this is "does there exist an $n$-digit number $a$ such that $a^2 \equiv a \pmod{10^n}$?" Since $10^n=2^n\cdot 5^n$, we can conclude that $a^2 \equiv a \pmod{2^n}$ and $a^2 \equiv a \pmod{5^n}$. However, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375243/help-with-proof-of-showing-idempotents-in-set-of-integers-modulo-a-prime-power-a), we know that the only way this can be true is if:
$$a \equiv 0,1 \pmod{2^n}$$
and likewise:
$$a \equiv 0,1 \pmod{5^n}$$

Now, if $a \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n}$ and $a \equiv 0 \pmod{5^n}$, then by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we get $a \equiv 0 \pmod{10^n}$. Similarly, if they're both $1$, we get $a \equiv 1 \pmod{10^n}$. Neither of these numbers are $n$-digits, so we can conclude that we need these numbers to be different, so we get the following two systems:
$$a \equiv 0 \pmod{2^n} \wedge a \equiv 1 \pmod{5^n}$$
$$a \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n} \wedge a \equiv 0 \pmod{5^n}$$

Now, we must prove that either the solution to the first system or the solution to the second system must be such that $a \geq 10^{n-1}$ so that $a$ is a $n$-digit number. This is as far as I got with this problem alone.

However, [@Michael](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822589/does-there-exist-such-a-number/1822614?noredirect=1#comment3724991_1822614) suggests adding the two systems together. If we say the solution to the first is $a_1$ and the solution to the second is $a_2$, then:
$$a_1+a_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^n} \wedge a_1+a_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{5^n}$$
Thus, we get:
$$a_1+a_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{10^n}$$
However, if we choose $a_1$ and $a_2$ to be $n$ or less digit numbers, given that $a_1 > 1$ since $1$ is not a solution to the first system and $a_2 > 1$ since $1$ is not a solution to the first system, we get $a_1+a_2 > 1$. We also get $a_1 < 10^n$ and $a_2 < 10^n$ since $a_1,a_2$ are at most $n$ digits, so $a_1+a_2 < 2\cdot 10^n$. Thus, the only possible suitable solution is $a_1+a_2=10^n+1$.

Now, if $a_1,a_2 < 10^{n-1}$, then $a_1+a_2 < 2\cdot 10^{n-1}$ which contradicts $a_1+a_2=10^n+1$. Thus, by contradiction, either $a_1 \geq 10^{n-1}$ or $a_2 \geq 10^{n-1}$.

Now, even though we've proved that there is a solution of $n$-digits, we're not quite done with the problem. Let's refer to the bigger of $a_1$ and $a_2$ as $a_s$. We need to prove that $a_s^2$ is $2n$ digits (and not $2n-1$ digits) because that's what the problem asks us. Since $a_1+a_2=10^n+1$, we can conclude that $a_s$ is bigger than one-half of $10^n+1$ (because otherwise, we would be summing two numbers less than one-half of $10^n+1$, which gives us a sum less than that number), meaning that $a_s > 5\cdot 10^{n-1}$. We also have $a_s < 10^n$ from before, so:
$$5\cdot 10^{n-1} < a_s < 10^n$$
This is an inequality of all positive numbers, so we can safely square everything.
$$25 \cdot 10^{2n-2} < a_s < 10^{2n}$$
The left side is a $2n$-digit number and the right side is the smallest $2n+1$-digit number possible, so the middle must be a $2n$-digit number, finally concluding the proof that an $n$-digit number $a$ with $2n$-digit $a^2$ exists such that $a^2 \equiv a \pmod{10}$.

Comment: I don't see how the problem you are solving here is equivalent to my problem.

Comment: @Puzzled417 You ask for a number where if we square it, it has the same last $n$ digits. The same last $n$ digits is the remainder of a number by $10^n$, so if $a$ and $a^2$ have the same last $n$ digits, then $a^2 \equiv a \pmod{10^n}$.

Comment: The question is not asking for the same last digits but equality.

Comment: The question says $(\overline{a_n...a_1})^2=\overline{a_{2n}...a_1}$. The number $\overline{a_n...a_1}$ has the last $n$ digits of itself because it is only $n$ digits. $\overline{a_{2n}...a_1}$ has the last $n$ digits of $\overline{a_n...a_1}$. Therefore, they have the same last $n$ digits and therefore: $$\overline{a_{2n}...a_1} \equiv \overline{a_n...a_1} \pmod{10^n}$$ We can substitute the left side for: $$(\overline{a_n...a_1})^2 \equiv \overline{a_n...a_1} \pmod{10^n}$$ And thus: $$a^2 \equiv a \pmod{10^n}$$ where $a$ is an $n$-digit number, so $a \geq 10^{n-1}$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak How do you know that $a^2$ has $2n$ digits? It might have $2n-1$ digits, i.e., me might need to accept leading zeroes. For example $25^2=0625$ (but we have $76^2=3776$ t the rescue). Or $09376^2=087909376$ (but we have $90625^2=8212890625$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen At the very least, I'm pretty sure the question asks for $a_n \neq 0$ since $a$ is an $n$-digit number and thus $a \geq 10^{n-1}$. Basically, the question asks us to show that for each $n$, at least one of the solutions in my answer is such that $a \geq 10^{n-1}$ or for us to show a counterexample where both solutions have less than $n$ digits. This proof/counterexample is what I'm still trying to figure out. I'm also assuming that $a^2$ has $2n$-digits and thus $a^2 \geq 10^{2n-1}$, but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: @NobleMushtak, hint: Look at 25+76=101

Comment: @Michael or at $09376 + 90625$ - facepalm!

Comment: @Michael Thanks so much! I've finished the problem above.